# How to remove Carriage return values in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have code to remove carriage return values,it is giving my desired result but every time i have to open excel sheet and run macro.Can you please help me remove carriage return values for all files in a folder without opening excel file.

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're really after here is how to iterate through files in a folder, and then use your sub-routine on each one of those file.  For the first part (iteration) take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba).

What you can then do is within the loop call your `RemoveCarriageReturns()` sub-routine.  You'll have a nested loop with your current implementation, which isn't ideal, but if the performance hit isn't too big, you'll be alright.  Alternatively, you can refactor your `RemoveCarriageReturns()` sub-routine to have less internal looping using something like [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/14/find-and-replace-all).

Comment: All that said, this will still open each excel file in the folder -- it will just do it programmatically.  I'm making the assumption that that's okay, even though you said you didn't want to open the excel files in your original question.